# Connection Failure to a HornetQ topic embedded in a JBOSS EAP 6.2

Tags: java, jms, hornetq, jboss-eap-6

I am trying to connect remotely to a topic configured on a HornetQ embedded in a JBOSS EAP 6.2. I've tryied different approaches to do so, but all gave me the same error:

```
javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory
at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:676)
at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createTopicConnection(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:196)
at TesteTags.main(TesteTags.java:82)
Caused by: HornetQConnectionTimedOutException[errorType=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT message=HQ119013: Timed out waiting to receive cluster topology. Group:null]
at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:950)
at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:672)
... 2 more
```

I followed the information on this quickstart: [Jboss Eap Quickstart: helloworld-jms](https://github.com/jboss-eap/quickstart/tree/master-eap6/helloworld-jms)

Follow my code:

```
try {
    final Properties env = new Properties();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
    env.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://localhost:4447");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "testuser");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "testpassword");

    Context context = new InitialContext(env);
    TopicConnectionFactory factory = (TopicConnectionFactory) context.lookup("jms/RemoteConnectionFactory");
    Topic topic = (Topic) context.lookup("jms/topic/myTopic");


    Connection connection = factory.createTopicConnection("testuser", "testpassword"); // The Error occurred here
    connection.start();
    Session session = connection.createSession(false, TopicSession.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE); 
    MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(topic);

    Message message = session.createTextMessage("My Test Message");

    producer.send(message);

    System.out.println("It Worked!");
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("It Failed!");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am using a standalone-full-ha profile with the default configurations.

Am I doing something wrong on my code? Or is there any configuration different from default that I have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of researching and testing, I solved the problem. First, I changed the dependency of the jboss-as-jms-client-bom-7.2.0 to this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-as-jms-client-bom</artifactId>
    <version>7.1.2.Final</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Also, I changed my code to use this different approach to connect to the server:

```
Connection connection = null;
Session session = null;
Formatter formatter = new Formatter();
Map<String, Object> connectionParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
connectionParams.put(TransportConstants.PORT_PROP_NAME, 5445);
connectionParams.put(TransportConstants.HOST_PROP_NAME, "localhost");

TransportConfiguration transportConfiguration = new TransportConfiguration(
    NettyConnectorFactory.class.getName(), connectionParams);

try {
    HornetQConnectionFactory cf = HornetQJMSClient
        .createConnectionFactoryWithHA(JMSFactoryType.CF, transportConfiguration);

    connection = cf.createConnection("testuser", "testpassword");

    connection.start();
    session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

    Topic topicTarifas = session.createTopic("tarifas.01101");
    MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(topicTarifas);

    Message message = session.createTextMessage("My Test Message");

    producer.send(message);

    System.out.println("It Worked!");
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("It Failed!");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hope this may be useful for someone else :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you compiled your client code with the same HornetQ libraries that ship with the version of JBoss EAP you’re using? You have to know that there is a version compatibility issue which does not allow the interoperability of different HornetQ versions.

Comment: I am using this library:

[jboss-as-jms-client-bom-7.2.0](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.as/jboss-as-jms-client-bom/7.2.0.Final)

Anyway, I have tried different versions and it made no difference.